# Can't use executeScript with a file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to inject a script with chrome.tabs.executeScript() but I get this error:

*Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Failed to load file: "contentscript.js"*

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

    // Inject script into current tab
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'contentscript.js'});
}
```

My manifest has the **tabs** and the exact **host** permission.

Comment: That error message cannot be more obvious... Double-check whether the file exists at the expected location (at the root of your extension). If you're using case-sensitive file system, check whether the capitalization is correct.

Comment: That was the issue, thank you! I was running the function from background.js, which was in the same folder as contentscript.js. For me that made more sense. The documentation is not very clear about this (and many other things).

Comment: What was the path it ended up being set to? I'm running the same problem at the moment.

Comment: @atwellpub The script has to be at the root of the extension.